# Eclipse: No Action Available in build path, no Java option available in Project properties

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gitlab

I did clone the project from Git repository.

Imported project in eclipse but I cannot see packages and proper project structure

I searched and looked for solution:

- In Build Path it says: No Action Available
- In Project properties: No Java option is available
- No option available in Builders

Also I created new workspace and tried but no luck.

Please let me know how can I fix it.

**Please check below images.**

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: As per the pics, it's looks like your maven is not able to download the plugins due to that the project is not getting imported properly.

Comment: Please check if you are connected through the internet. Or if you are behind the proxy than please do tje proxy settings in maven

Comment: @DeepakKumar i am connected to internet. If you looks are project root folder it is not showing me either 'M' or 'J' symbol which denoted Mavan or Java. Also when I right click on project it is not showing me Maven option

Comment: Are you using any VPN or proxy in your system?

Comment: nope, directly connected over a internet

Comment: Try to delete .m2 folder from your system.

Comment: in .metadata\.plugins ?

Comment: Sometimes maven cache some bad files frim .m2 and it won't download the new files from internet

Comment: C:\ users\<user system user>\.m2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218604/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-dhanesh).

Comment: Thanks a lot @DeepakKumar for helping me in sorting an issue. Issue was I was not importing a project as a Maven project.